# Magento 1.9.0.1 - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /path/to/magentoroot/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php on line 117

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, error, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I have Magento CE 1.9.0.1 installed in one of my client's website and when I add any product to cart and go to `checkout` - `onepage`, I am getting below error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /path/to/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php on line 117
```

Nothing else is there in the php error log and I have tried replacing the `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php` with the original Magento 1.9.0.1 's `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php` file too, but no luck.

PHP version running on the server is 5.6.31 and have also tried installing this patch - https://gist.github.com/renttek/29beaaa1e90909639501, but the error is still there when going to checkout in guest mode.

I don't think any major changes has been done to any of the core files.

Anyone faced this same issue before or any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have Opcache enabled? if so, did you try restarting the php process on the server, after reverting to the stock file?

Comment: "stock file" ? Do you mean original Magento core counterpart of Cc.php ?

Comment: Yes. By default, PHP doesn't check for timestamp changes on the Zend OpCache, so it'll load the old version until restarted / purged.

Comment: I checked the `phpinfo()`, it doesn't show the entry for `opcache` and also in "Configure Command" it is displayed as `'--disable-opcache'`, so I guess it would be disabled right ?

Comment: If you are available for chat right now, can we chat ? If so please send me chat request.

Comment: Yes. Not sure how to invite you to chat here

Answer (score 0):

After discussion in chat, it turns out this site had been compromised. Recommend restoring all original Magento core files, and installing latest patches.